# Parsley to validate a file was uploaded?

Tags: grails, parsley.js

I am using Parsley throughout an application on text fields and selects. Is there a way to use Parsley to validate a file was uploaded within a file input?

```
<input type="file" name="letterFile1" class="custom-file-input" data-parsley-required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a custom validator, with Parsley.

```
window.ParsleyConfig = {
validators: {
  filerequired: {
    fn: function (value, requirements) {
      if (value=="")  return false;
      else return true;
     },
    priority: 32
  }
}
```

};